# Change static (li)st item to icons

Tags: html, css, wordpress, list, taxonomy

Short story: I want to change list items to unique icon for each list item.

Long story: 
Im using a directory theme(Listable) in wp, users can choose 0-3 options from a custom checklist, with taxonomy "job_listing_type"(Im using wp manager field editor plugin). The plugin output the choices in a li form (plain HTML). I would like to have icons instead of text.

For example: this could be the output from the checklist:

```
<div id="jmfe-wrap-job_serveras" class="jmfe-custom-field-wrap">
  <li id="jmfe-custom-job_serveras" class="jmfe-custom-field ">Alkohol</li>
  <li id="jmfe-custom-job_serveras" class="jmfe-custom-field ">Endast vegetariskt</li>
  <li id="jmfe-custom-job_serveras" class="jmfe-custom-field ">Griskött</li>
</div>
```

As you see, the li id is static, therefore I can not do the text to icon change by pointing them out. It is possible to change the "li" to whatever I like.

This is how I want to display the list items:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to do it? Does not matter if css or javascript, whatever works in Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [fontawesome](http://fontawesome.io/) or bootstrap's [glyphicon](http://getbootstrap.com/components/).
all you need to do is including the css and js documents of the library.